# Qlikview expression not affected by selection EXCEPT two specific fields

Tags: qlikview

I have a Qlikview expression that I want it to not be affected by any selections EXCEPT two specific fields: `Year` & `Month`.

My Expression is:

```
Sum(Aggr(IF(Duration = 0.5 , 0.5,
IF(DayName = 'Sat',0,
IF(DayName = 'Sun',0,
RangeSum(
Count({<Key = {"=Len(Trim([Date From])) > 0"}>}DISTINCT Name),
Avg({<Key = {"=Len(Trim([Date From])) = 0"}>}0))))), Name, ADate))
```

I know you can use something like; `{1<Year  = $:: Year>}` & `{1<Month  = $:: Month>}` to accomplish this but I cant quite get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways to accomplish this, but if you're sure you want the expression to consider only the two fields you mentioned, I like to start with the total set of all data and filter to just the ones you want.

You are basically there, depending on what expression you want restricted you'd use `{1<Year  = $:: Year>}` or `{1<Month  = $:: Month>}` like you said in any place you want restricted. The `1` set identifier will start with the total set of all data in the application, then the set modifiers, `Year` and `Month` will be set based on selection in the default state designated by the `$` set identifier.

So something like this should work I think:

```
Sum({1<Year=$::Year, Month=$::Month>}
    Aggr(
        IF( Duration = 0.5 , 0.5,
            IF(DayName = 'Sat', 0,
                IF(DayName = 'Sun', 0,
                    RangeSum({
                        Count({<Key = {"=Len(Trim([Date From])) > 0"}>} DISTINCT Name),
                        Avg({<Key = {"=Len(Trim([Date From])) = 0"}>} 0 )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
    Name, ADate)
)
```

You may have to add this to your `count` and `avg` expressions as well.

I am confused about this expression: `Avg({<Key = {"=Len(Trim([Date From])) = 0"}>} 0 )`. It is averaging 0. Is that right?